# Adding a method to an object that is serialized, but it doesnt' need to be serialized

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an object that is currently serialized, and I want to do add a method to this class.  The method shouldn't be serialized as it doesn't hold any state or anything, but it will modify the classes data but this doesn't need to be serialized (it will parse the value of a serializable string property).

How can I add this method?  Or should I have this method on another utility class instead?

Comment: If you meant a property, you can add the `XmlIgnore` attribute

Answer (score 4):

Methods aren't serialized. Only properties and fields are serialized. And Properties are only eligible for serialization if using DataContractSerializer (BinaryFormatter will only serialize Properties' underlying fields).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this method won't be a problem, methods aren't serialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the class then as I understand it serialization deals with properties and fields.  Methods don't need to be and don't get serialized.  They process the data

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Most cases shouldn't affect unserialize an object.

Answer (score 0):

Only fields are serialized. Methods and properties arent (properties are methods). The XmlSerializer is an exception; it only looks at public properties, and those must be public get / set if you are to deserialize them.